# Python XML parsing with ElementTree: How to find values of elements with the same name?

Tags: python, xml

Disclaimer: I am new to Python, XML, and programming in general. The code (that I stole from the internet) works but has some problems that I can't seem to find the answer to or wrap my brain around...

I am trying to parse XML files from the [grants.gov xml extract website](http://www.grants.gov/web/grants/xml-extract.html) with the goal of removing all of the grants that are not in the "unrestricted" eligibility category (Tagged in the XML with an "EligibilityCategory" of "99".) and outputting a new xml file.

The code I have below properly removes the funding opps of no interest but also removes funding opps that have multiple EligibilityCategorys which also include a "99". I assume this is because .find only grabs the first occurrence moves on. I tried to use .findall but couldn't work it out. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for FundingOppSynopsis in root.findall('FundingOppSynopsis'): 
    ID = int(FundingOppSynopsis.find('EligibilityCategory').text)
    if ID != 99:
        root.remove(FundingOppSynopsis)

tree.write("Output/output.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8', method="xml")
```

Sample (significantly shaved down) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Grants SYSTEM "http://apply07.grants.gov/search/dtd/XMLExtract.dtd">
<Grants>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>USDA-RMA-RME-2008-03</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDate>03242008</ApplicationsDueDate>
        <Office>Risk Management Agency</Office>
        <Agency>Department of Agriculture</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>25</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>NPS-ARRAWHIS100315</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDate>11282009</ApplicationsDueDate>
        <Office>National Park Service</Office>
        <Agency>Department of the Interior</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>00</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>OFDA-FY08-002-APS</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDate>10102008</ApplicationsDueDate>
        <Office>None</Office>
        <Agency>Agency for International Development</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>99</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>AK-NOI08-0004</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDate>07142008</ApplicationsDueDate>
        <Office>Bureau of Land Management</Office>
        <Agency>Department of the Interior</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>99</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>RD-RBP-BIOMASS-2007-FULL</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDate>11162007</ApplicationsDueDate>
        <Office>Business and Cooperative Programs</Office>
        <Agency>Department of Agriculture</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>06</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>12</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>13</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>20</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>22</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>23</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>25</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
    <FundingOppSynopsis>
        <FundingOppNumber>BAA07-10</FundingOppNumber>
        <ApplicationsDueDateExplanation>The due dates and times established for the receipt of White Papers and Full Proposals are as indicated in Section IV, Paragraph 3 of the BAA. </ApplicationsDueDateExplanation>
        <Office>Office of Procurement Operations - Grants Division</Office>
        <Agency>Department of Homeland Security</Agency>
        <EligibilityCategory>00</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>01</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>02</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>04</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>05</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>06</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>07</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>08</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>11</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>12</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>13</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>20</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>21</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>22</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>23</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>25</EligibilityCategory>
        <EligibilityCategory>99</EligibilityCategory>
    </FundingOppSynopsis>
</Grants>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract a list of categories with findall and then check if 99 is in that list. You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
for FundingOppSynopsis in root.findall('FundingOppSynopsis'): 
    IDs = [int(category.text) for category in FundingOppSynopsis.findall('EligibilityCategory')]
    if 99 not in IDs:
        root.remove(FundingOppSynopsis)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm choosing this answer because I'm still very new at python and this answer fits perfectly into the tree.write method of file output.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a xPath request to achieve what you want to do.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

req = tree.findall("./FundingOppSynopsis[EligibilityCategory='99']")

for r in req:
    print r
```

The request i made return a list of all FundingOppSynopsis elements of the documents who have a child tagged EligibilityCategory containing the text '99'.

More info about xPath request [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

More info about xPath usage in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

Comment: Ah! I was trying to do that but instead of completely writing out "FundingOppSynopsis" I used a "*". I'm sure I had other syntax errors in there somewhere but I got frustrated, deleted it, and started again from scratch.  Thank you!